# Running simple terminal commands in command palette VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to run simple terminal commands in Command Palette? Or an extension for it?

For example, something like `rm unwantedfile.txt` would be super useful to do in via command palette rather than having to open up the integrated terminal or do the task via mouse (mainly interested in not having to take my hands off the keyboard).

I know there's [Edit with Shell Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.edit-with-shell), but it doesn't appear to be able to edit outside the file itself.

Comment: Just `ctrl+\``to get the integrated terminal and type away. No difference to typing in command pallet. If you don't like `ctrl+\`` you can customize it.

Comment: That fair. I guess I was going after more of an aesthetics improvement more than anything. Seems a bit disorienting to have to bring up the entire console for a really simple command.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use VS Code built-in functionality using shortcuts. Just add to `keybindings.json`:

```js
{
  "key": "cmd+shift+R",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "clear; rails server\u000D"
  }
},
```

Or you can take a look at this extension, [Command Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=edonet.vscode-command-runner), that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: On Mac push `Shift`+`Command`+`P` then type "keyboard" and after a few options pop up choose `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` to open `keybindings.json`. Then add your custom command there using format as described above in the answer. The "\u000D" is an EOL character.